# Laravel - Can't change default cache driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to change cache driver from **file** to **redis** or **apc**, but everytime when I said `dd(\Cache::getDefaultDriver());` it gives me that "file" as default cache driver.

I cleared config and stored cache, but it still continue..

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

in my config/cache.php

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

What should I do ? I'm working on local and my laravel version is 5.6

Comment: add it in .env and run again php artisan serve

Comment: @amini.swallow But I already changed in config folder, is that neccesary too ? As so far as I know when you already cached the config files, laravel doesn't look env file

Comment: I do not know why but for me it does not work in config too and i edit it in env, maybe your problem is same

Comment: I think if you delete cache driver in env , the config will work

Comment: well, I changed env file and now it working oddly, thanks brother. you may want to add this comment as an answer, may be help anothers..

Comment: @amini.swallow But I don't get the logic.. I changed config file and cleared config cache, it should be work you know..

Comment: did you remove cache driver in .env and check again?

Comment: yes that works as well too, But as I mentioned above, this shouldn't be neccessary

Comment: I think 'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'redis'), means if cache_driver does not exist in .env use redis! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please change

> CACHE_DRIVER = redis

in `.env`

to redis and again run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 1):

1) `composer require predis/predis`
2) in `config/database.php` paste these codes below..

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

3) CACHE_DRIVER=redis in .env file